# How do I see how many combinations of specific values there are in columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Group          ID   
UP              1
UP              1
UP              2
UP              2
UP              2
UP              1  
UP              1
UP              2
UP              2
UP              1
UP              1
```

Is there any way to see how many times a 1 is under a 1 in the ID column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(flag = case_when(ID == 1 & lag(ID) == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% pull(flag) %>% sum
[1] 3
```

Comment: @StackOverload9, just change `ID == 2`

Answer (score 0):

Base R :

```
sum(df$ID == 1 & c(tail(df$ID, -1), NA) == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

You can also use `dplyr::lag` and `data.table::shift`

```
sum(df$ID == 1 & dplyr::lag(df$ID) == 1, na.rm = TRUE)

sum(df$ID == 1 & data.table::shift(df$ID) == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```